# I'm trying to write something that will fill out an Australia Post Declaration Form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've got basic proficiency in PHP, JavaScript, html, and SQL. I also use Postman little a bit. I hope a solution to my problem can be found within those skills, but I'm willing to learn a new language if necessary.

Using PHP, I've written myself a page of admin tools to be able to run my business. One feature I'd like, is an ability to prefill a customs declaration form (found [here](https://auspost.com.au/declaration-form-fields-page)).

My first idea was to download the html page and run it, because if that works, all I need to do is fill out the form with PHP.

That failed. Even after changing all the relative paths to absolute paths, I still ran into the `cors policy no 'access-control-allow-origin' header is present on the requested resource.` issue.

Ideally, I'd like to bypass the page entirely and skip straight to where-ever the form submits to, but if that cannot be done, I'd happily settle for a button that navigates to a prefilled version of the page.

I respect that answering this question fully could take all day, but I'll happily award the green tick to anyone who can just give me a starting point to solve this problem from.

Maybe I just need the right header. Maybe there's a way to get my browser to treat the site as if it's at the same origin.

I've spent ages searching everywhere for a solution to this problem, but most people with this problem were trying to access their own resources, not someone else's.

Comment: Is this the best place for this question? Or should I have used StackOverflow?

Comment: Are you able to use in-browser tools? A custom addon for Firefox or Chrome should be able to modify the page in precisely the way you need. Alternatively (and perhaps easier to do) you can use a script manager addon such as Tampermonkey and write a script to prefill the fields for you.

Comment: @jla I have no idea how to do that, but I could learn. Not really tied to a particular browser, but I'm most familiar with Chrome's dev tools. I'll give "Tampermonkey" a google and see what I can come up with.

Comment: Have you tried bypassing the form entirely and just submitting to wherever the form submits to?

Comment: @user253751 Yup. The form action is "#". No idea how I'm supposed to submit to "#"

Comment: @JonathonPhilipChambers then it's probably running some javascript.

Comment: @user253751 it is. It's running so much JavaScript that I genuinely lack the skills to isolate the relevant script and decipher what it's doing. (Believe me, I've tried, but text searching can only get me so far.)

Comment: Investigating the network request when submitting a test shows the request is POSTed to https://auspost.com.au/bin/form/stopact with an escaped JSON string containing all the data. The response contains a customer reference code, QR code and other information. You could start by submitting data to that endpoint, with as many of the same headers as possible

Comment: At this point the question is probably more suitable for stackoverflow

Comment: @jla, yeah I thought it might be, but too late now. Already bountied. Anyway, if you submitted an answer with just that, you'd be in line to win the bounty. And not just on a technicality. That insight is genuinely worth 50 points to me. (Though, I'm still waiting out the 7 days)

Comment: Ah... okay, will repost on StackOverflow then. Thanks for my 50 points back.

Comment: @jla here's a link to the new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65386443/im-trying-to-write-something-that-will-fill-out-an-australia-post-declaration-f and I credited you for your insight. If you'd like to write it as an answer, I'll delete the quote and upvote the answer.